# select count/sum and true/false bit-flag at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

In my MySQL database I got three tables. One is a list of items having an ID and some more columns. The second one is a list of users with first name and so on. The third on records if a user has rated and/or bought an item. The data type of the column for rated and bought will be a bit-flag (1/0).

[image: rating table]

So, now I would like to return in **only one** SQL query how often an item was rated and if it was rated by the specific users.

Input arguments are:

- user
- item

Result should be:

- count(rated)
- true/false(rated by specified user)

[image]

Comment: The number of users (which means the number of columns in the resultset) should be dynamic ?

Comment: The second picture is just for understanding. Let's say I query with an SQL statement for item=1 and user=1. Then I would like to get in return how often the item has been rated (by all users) and if user 1 has rated item 1 or not. I found this one: **select count(*), count(case when user = 1 then 1 else null end) from rating where item = 1** But is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *pivot*.

```
SELECT item, SUM(rated) AS no_rated, SUM(bought) AS no_bought,
        MAX(user = 1 AND rated = 1) AS rated_by_1,
        MAX(user = 2 AND rated = 1) AS rated_by_2,
        MAX(user = 1 AND bought = 1) AS bought_by_1,
        MAX(user = 2 AND bought = 2) AS bought_by_2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY item
```

See [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) for more information about pivoting in MySQL. If the number of users is dynamic, so you can't hard-code them as I did, you'll need to write dynamic SQL. There are links to some web sites showing how to do this in the answers to that question.

Comment: That's a good idea. For me it's easier though I'm only asking for one item and one user at the time.

Comment: @Matthias: Then simply add `WHERE item = 1`and remove the two lines for user = 2.